# How to restrict the ListActivity to show only one item

Tags: android, listactivity

Its very simple, I have a `ListActivity` I want to show only one item in it.
I have tried

```
ListView listView = getListView();
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

I have also tried

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 1;
    }
```

The second one throws a `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` Exception and crashes the app.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: post the stacktrace and the some more relevant code

Comment: If you need only 1 item ListView is not the right choice. You can have a simple view that does the trick.